# "This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key" error when changing project from storyboard to xib files

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

I had lots of progress in a project which started using both storyboards and xib files. Then I decided to change it all to xib files so that firmwares older than 5.0 could use them. I had some trouble doing that so I created a new project and began copying all of the code and content of the xib files. However, when I ran the project, the debugger gave me the error "This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key gameStarts"(name of an outlet). I already tried cleaning all targets from the DerivedData folder, resetting my iOS simulator, and checking in the connections inspector of the designated xib file for rare outlets, but nothing seems to work. I have searched for hours without success. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It *probably* means that an instance somewhere (a view controller, etc.) hasn't had its class name set properly.  This would cause it to be instantiated at runtime with a lesser type (e.g. default `UIViewController`), which of course has none of your custom methods so it's not KVO-compliant for your own keys.

Comment: Your answer sounds good but isn't the view controller set to it's corresponding class through the file's owner? Because I checked the identity inspector and the xib's file's owner is connected to the appropriate class.

Comment: Do you use `.xib` file references when setting controllers?  For instance, in a tab view if you set a tab's view controller to something in another `.xib` file, you must set your custom view controller subclass in *both* the tab's settings *and* the other `.xib` file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the .xib file has a outlet reference to gameStarts, but in the controller file, there isn't a IBOutlet property gameStarts. The most easy way to check whether you have set it properly in xCode 4 is switching to the xib file, selected the file's owner, click on the triangle on the right of the class name. This should bring you to the class file. I met similar problems before, they were caused by the incorrect reference.

And also find the element which is connected to gameStarts in xib file, re-connect it to your controller. I guess you would have copied the interface from storyboard file.